# Strange white line with \lstnewenvironment

Tags: environments

I'm trying to write a `\lstnewenvironment` for my LaTeX class but I have a strange behaviour.

Here's my code :

```
\lstnewenvironment{console} {
   \lstset {
      basicstyle=\color{lightgrey}\scriptsize\ttfamily,
      backgroundcolor=\color{black},
      breaklines=true,
      numberstyle=\scriptsize,
      columns=flexible,
      keepspaces=true,
  }
}{}
```

And here's the result :

[image]

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I only see this behaviour in Preview.app on Mac OS but not in Chrome's pdf viewer!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Most likely an artifact of the PDF viewer, but without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) it is difficult to know for sure.

Comment: As @PeterGrill says, these lines probably won't show up when you print your document. If they stay just 1 pixel thick, even on maximum zoom factor in Preview, then they're not "really" there. What you could do as a workaround is: don't set the background colour using the `listings` package, since that colours each line separately, but instead put your whole `lstlistings` environment inside a box that has a black background colour.

Answer (score 2):

[Combining Peter and John's comments as an answer]

The thin horizontal lines are an artefact caused by the PDF viewer. If they stay just 1 pixel thick, even on maximum zoom factor in Preview, then they're not "really" there and almost certainly won't appear in print. (The PDF spec does not seek to ensure that 'out by one' issues with sub-pixel difference do not occur, in contrast to DVI.)

A workaround: don't set the background colour using the `listings` package, since that colours each line separately, but instead put your whole `lstlistings` environment inside a box that has a black background colour.