# Listing removing horizontal lines and autocrop to the size of code fragment

Tags: listings

I am trying to include the code in my presentation. There are two things that I need to fix:

- there are horizontal lines appearing between the code lines
- I do not want to use the entire page, need to autocrop to the size of the code

Gray horizontal lines between code lines:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} %used for font color
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1} 
\lstset{
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{White},
     language=Java,
     tabsize=1,
     xleftmargin=20pt,
     keywordstyle=\color{Red}\bf,
     showstringspaces=false,
     morekeywords={public, class},
     backgroundcolor=\color{Black}
 }

\begin{lstlisting}

public class MyObject{

    public MyObject(){
        System.out.println("MyObject");
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118158/strange-white-line-with-lstnewenvironment

Comment: Does my answer solve your issue?

Comment: @karlkoeller I could not test your solution until now. I have commented under your answer. There is a compilation error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `tcolorbox`.

First of all, we define a new listing style `mystyle` through `\lstdefinestyle` instead of defining a `\lstset`. This is needed after. **It is important that you remove the `backgroundcolor` option from it**.

Then we define a new listing environment `mylisting` through `\newtcblisting`. The option `listing options={style=mystyle}` is to use the previously defined style `mystyle`. The option `hbox`, instead, crops the contents of the listing to its size.

At this point, use the environment `mylisting` instead of `lstlisting`. The white lines disappear because the box is filled with black color, while with normal `lstlisting` the background is printed line by line.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} %used for font color
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{White},
     language=Java,
     tabsize=1,
     keywordstyle=\color{Red}\bf,
     showstringspaces=false,
     morekeywords={public, class}
 }

\newtcblisting{mylisting}{
      arc=0pt,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=0mm,
      left=0mm,
      right=0mm,
      boxrule=0pt,
      colback=black,
      listing only,
      listing options={style=mystyle},
      hbox
}

\begin{mylisting}
public class MyObject{

    public MyObject(){
        System.out.println("MyObject");
    }
}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Getting this error:``./test.tex:41: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/hbox' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. [\end{mylisting}]``

Comment: I have got the latest version of texlive, 2013.

Comment: No, updates. I have reinstalled the newest version now, still no success.

Comment: @user3232 I have Package: tcolorbox 2014/02/06 version 2.70, and you (have a look at the log file)

Comment: @karkoeller Updating to the version 2.70 fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @karkoeller When I updated recently I got version 2.71, and it stopped working. The error is: `Package pgfkeys Error I do not know the key '/tcb/stringstyle' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` Any clues?

Comment: @user3232 I, too, have version 2.71, but it compiles fine.